# laravel auth and session not persisting

Tags: session, authentication, laravel

The laravel session and auth I use have some problem in server, **but working really fine in localhost** . I will show.

**Route**

```
Route::get('/signin', 'PageController@signin');
Route::get('/signup', 'PageController@signup');
Route::get('/terms', 'PageController@terms');
Route::resource('/', 'PageController');
Route::controller('user', 'UserController');
```

**PageController**

```
public function index() {
         if (Auth::check()) {
            return View::make('user.index');
        } else {
            return View::make('landing');
        }       
    }
```

**UserController**

```
public function postLogin() {           
        $data = array();            
        $secured = ['user_email' => $_POST['email'], 'password' => $_POST['password']];
        if (Auth::attempt($secured, isset($_POST['remember']))) {
            if (Auth::user()->user_status == 1 ) {
                return Redirect::to('/');
            } else {
                $data['success'] = false;
            }
        } else {
            $data['success'] = false;
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

`Auth::check()` fails in pagecontoller even after login succeds. But if I change the code to

**UserController**

```
    public function postLogin() {           
        $data = array();            
        $secured = ['user_email' => $_POST['email'], 'password' => $_POST['password']];
        if (Auth::attempt($secured, isset($_POST['remember']))) {
            if (Auth::user()->user_status == 1 ) {
                return Return View::make(user.index);
            } else {
                $data['success'] = false;
            }
        } else {
            $data['success'] = false;
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

I get the index page and if I click the link of the home I get the landing page not the index page.

I guess I clarify my problem, I have gone through may solution replied earlier in same manner question nothing working.

I don't think its the server problem because another laravel application is working fine in same server.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query seems to be incomplete, from what i understand you are able to get the index page after passing the authentication check only once, and that is by using this method:

```
public function postLogin() {
    $data = array();
    $secured = ['user_email' => $_POST['email'], 'password' => $_POST['password']]; 
   if (Auth::attempt($secured, isset($_POST['remember']))) {
   if (Auth::user()->user_status == 1 ) { 
   return Return View::make(user.index); 
   } 
   else {
   $data['success'] = false; 
   } 
  } 
  else { 
   $data['success'] = false; 
   }
  return $data; 
  }
```

try using a different browser to make sure there is no cookie storage restrictions in the client side and check the app/config/session.php file and see if you have configured the HTTPS Only Cookies according to your needs.

and just on an additional note this line "return Return View::make(user.index);" looks vague.

Comment: Hi Arjun thanks for reply,  `return array(
 'driver' => 'file',

 'lifetime' => 0,

 'expire_on_close' => true,

 'files' => storage_path().'/sessions',

 'connection' => null,

 'table' => 'sessions',

 'lottery' => array(2, 100),

 'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
 
 'path' => '/',

 'domain' => null,

 'secure' => false,

);` this is the session.php file. As you said the index fun in the pageController determine index or landing page if I redirecrt to '/' . I checked in other browser but no luck.

Comment: @it'sme change the 'lifetime' => 0

Comment: Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
to be allowed to remain idle before it expires.

Comment: The session is already set to 0.  This is my auth.php file  `return array(    

     'driver' => 'eloquent',

     'model' => 'User',

     'table' => 'mcs_users',

     'reminder' => array(

         'email' => 'emails.auth.reminder',

         'table' => 'password_reminders',

         'expire' => 60,

     ),

);`  All is working fine in localhost, but not in server.

Comment: @ it'sme, it should not be 0, this value represents the time in minutes. You can specify 15 for 15 mins and so on.

Comment: @it'sme, and also check if you have multiple configurations set for various environments like production, development, etc

Comment: I set the lifetime 120 okay, but i just find out that the laravel is generating multiple file at single login, that might be the problem.

Comment: @ it'sme, well if you want to debug it that way then see the app/storage/sessions directory for sessions file generated when a user logs in and verify it with your settings given in the config file, additionally you may intercept the HTTP traffic using some intercepting proxies like Burp( or even Firefox Inbuilt "Shift+F2" or Chrome's Developer toolbar and see the network) while a user logs in and check the server's response headers to debug the issue.

Comment: Hi, www.mycopyspot.com is the site. I have created an account user@gmail.com, user1234  . Please login you get the index page but if you click the logo that refresh page will lead to landing page to signin again.

Comment: a:4:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"HJL0PNUKWRLmuzNnolbjpY08xp8vC6iJ7Yf7og9h";s:38:"login_82e5d2c56bdd0811318f0cf078b78bfc";i:1;s:9:"_sf2_meta";a:3:{s:1:"u";i:1407740753;s:1:"c";i:1407740753;s:1:"l";s:1:"0";}s:5:"flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}}   this is the one of the 20 session file created at a single login. No idea whats happening.

Comment: Your server is not sending any set cookie headers to the client browser that is why the session is not persistent in the browser..most probably some settings issue with laravel session or could be even PHP specific..check the php.ini file aswell..why dont you start with a fresh installation of Laravel and implement your domain logic in that fresh instance.

Comment: **Hi Arjun thanks for your support**. I don't understand what the reason was for that error. But when I get a fresh laravel installation for my project **it worked**. I was editing the files of my previous project for the new one.